# Android M camera torchMode change frequency

Tags: android

I am testing the new Camera API. I want to use the camera torch as a strobe. The strobe frequency can be changed via a seekbar. The camera flash turns on at the initial value of 1000 ms, but the strobe frequency never changes even if the value variable is changed.  I think my problem is that I am using a Timer for the strobe function. I have a variable value which is changed via the seekbar, but clearly the value is never changing inside the strobe Timer function.

```
CameraManager cameraManager;
    String[] camId;
    Camera camera;

    ViewGroup parentLayout;

    int value = 1000;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final EditText editText = (EditText)
                findViewById(R.id.editText);


    cameraManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
            try {
                camId = cameraManager.getCameraIdList();
            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                strobe();
            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


        final SeekBar skbar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        skbar.incrementProgressBy(1);
        skbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {



            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                                          boolean fromUser) {




                value = progress * 10;


                    editText.setText(value + " ms");


            }
        });



    }

    public void strobe() throws CameraAccessException {

        new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    cameraManager.setTorchMode(camId[0], true);
                } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    cameraManager.setTorchMode(camId[0], false);
                } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        }, 0, value);


    }
```

Answer (score -1):

apart from any possible problem in your code, te "setTorchMode" API takes 1/3 to 1 second (!) to finish. No way that that API can be used for your purpose. And maybe that is the problem in your code too...